# Displaying images from the storage folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, storage, laravel-7

I don't want to publicly access able my user photos but I want to show them on the admin panel. How?

I try this :

```
Storage::get($fileName);
```

**My .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]  

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]   

</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can create shortcuts for those files I presume in Laravel

Comment: How to create shortcuts?

Comment: I meant symbolic links but it doesn't seem to fully fit your use case. You may have to create some route layer which checks if session is of admin and then only loads the image.

Comment: If there aren't many images, you can show a base64 version of the image rather than an asset URL.

Comment: I have multiple users I want to display their data as table data with an image .

Comment: Have you tried using a middle ware?

Comment: No. I didn't try middleware. How to use middleware in this case?

Comment: You will have to use .htaccess to reroute secret asset files to a particular laravel route and then use a middleware to check current user type and then load the image.

Comment: Can you provide me an example for better understanding?

Comment: How do you check if a user is an admin?

Comment: I check the user is admin or not by using the laravel gate.

Comment: I am developing a site for an education institute. It has a visitor area and student or teacher admin panel. if any visitor goes this URL 'example.com/storage' he/she can access my list of all files and images.  which I don't want. I want to block visitors to access some folder In storage.

Comment: Can you edit your post and show how your .htaccess looks like?

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` would look this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.+?/?assets/images [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]   

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]   

</IfModule>
```

*In the above* the important lines are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.+?/?assets/images [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It says if the current request is of `assets/images` and if the request is a file name, then pass it to `index.php` which will basically go to the `routes/web.php`.

**routes/web.php:**

```
Route::middleware(['admin-access'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('assets/images/{file_name}',function($file_name){
        header('Content-type:image/jpeg');// can improve to detect file extension and render accordingly.
        readfile(public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'assets' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name);
        exit;
    });
});
```

Above route suggests that if the request is passed by `admin-access`, then only load the image.

**AdminAccess Middlware:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class AdminAccess
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        if(Auth::user->isAdmin()){ // or whatever you do to check
          return $next($request);    
        }

        return response("Permission denied.",403);
    }
}
```

Make sure you add `admin-access` in **kernel.php** as well.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'admin-access' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAccess::class,
        ....
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Comment: If this solves your problem, make sure you check the tick mark on the left hand side to accept it. This will help others know it is a working solution. Also, I have assumed all images are in `public/assets/images` folder.

Comment: I am not familiar with StackOverflow. sorry.

Comment: No problem, what's the issue?

Comment: can you provide me a solution about how to retrieve file URL which is not in the **storage/app/public** folder? example: **storage/app/private **  . How to access those files?

Comment: @MdArafat You can do `php artisan storage:link` to create symbolic links in your public folder.

Comment: Sorry. yea my problem was solved. Thank you so much for your support.